# How can I assign boost::filesystem::directory_entry::path() value to a string?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to write an algorithm that iterates recursively through a directory and compares each folder, sub-folder and file name to a user-defined regex object.

I've found this piece of code for the iteration part:

```
path p(FilePath);
for (directory_entry& x : recursive_directory_iterator(p))
    std::cout << x.path() << '\n';
```

Where *Filepath* is the directory path defined by the user at runtime.

It works great to print out paths on the console, but I can't figure out a way to use path() to do what I want, which would be to assign its value to a string and then compare that string to my regex object.

I've been looking at other member function in boost::filesystem::directory_entry but I'm not really having any luck so far.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm dumb.

Comment: Take a look at `path::string()` or `path::generic_string()` from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers . So in your example, `x.path().string()` will give you the native format string

Comment: Thanks, we're on the right path, but I can't get path().string() to loop. I've edited my question to show what the problem is.

Comment: See my answer wrt your edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works great to print out paths on the console, but I can't figure
>   out a way to use path() to do what I want, which would be to assign
>   its value to a string and then compare that string to my regex object.

boost::path has got a string member that either performs a conversion to a string type, or returns a const reference to the underlying storage mechanism (typically std::string) ([see boost path documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-native-format-observers)). Therefore, just call:

```
x.path().string()
```

Also, you might want to add some braces behind your for loop:

```
path p(FilePath);
std::string temppath;
for (directory_entry& x : recursive_directory_iterator(p))
{
    temppath = x.path().string();
    std::cout << temppath << std::endl;
}
```

The way you structured the code, std::cout would not be called as part of the loop, but only after the loop completed in its entirety... classic bug!!!

Comment: Thanks, we're on the right path, but I can't get path().string() to loop. I've edited my question to show what the problem is.

Comment: I can't believe this... Thank you. I was thinking Python -.-